# Writing function for documented join operations

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that documents the input and output of each join operation in my script to enable me to review all operations once the script is done. Doing this, I want to make sure that no dataframes get inflated in the process due to redundant matches etc.

So far, I manually added a layer around each join operation. It illustrates what I want to do. First, take input file `file1`, join it with `file2` and create `file3`. `file3` can be either of the same name as `file1` or a new object. `checkmerge` is the documentation file which will get longer with each merge operation.

```
merge <- "file1+file2=file3"
count <-  nrow(file1)
check_t1 <- data.frame(merge, count)
file3<- join(file1, file2, by = ("firmid", "year"), type = "left")
count <- nrow(file3)
check_t2 <- data.frame(merge, count)
checkmerge <- rbind(checkmerge, check_t1, check_t2)
```

This works well for me. However, the manual progress (a) creates room for errors, (b) inflates the script and makes it difficult to read. So I want to write a function doing that. I am fairly new to writing functions, but the following was my approach (which did not work):

```
##Initialize checkmerge file

mergedat <- as.character(NULL)
countdat <- as.numeric(NULL)
checkmerge <- data.frame(mergedat, countdat)

##Define function    

fun.docmerge <- function(x, y, z, crit, typ, doc = checkmerge) {
      mergedat <- paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "+",
                        deparse(substitute(y)), "=", z)
      countdat <- nrow(x)
      check_t1 <- data.frame(mergedat, countdat)
      z <- join(x, y, by = crit, type = typ)
      countdat <- nrow(z)
      check_t2 <- data.frame(mergedat, countdat)
      doc <- rbind(doc, check_t1, check_t2)
    }
```

And then call to get the same result as in the first manual approach:

```
fun.docmerge(x = file1, y = file2, z = "file3", crit = c("firmid", "year"), typ = "left")
```

However, when calling the function, nothing happens. So the objects do not change and I also do not get an error message.

How can I adjust my function to replicate what I did manually before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in you function:
In the line `merge <- paste(x, "+", y, "=", z)`, the `x` and `y` are not the strings of the variable names, but the values of the dataframes. You could deal with that using:

```
paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "+",
    deparse(substitute(y)), "=", z)
```

By the way, `merge` is a base function in R, you shouldn't call new objects that way.

Furthermore, the line `checkmerge <- rbind(checkmerge, check_t1, check_t2)` refers to the object `checkmerge` that has not been created at this time. Replace it with `rbind(check_t1, check_t2)`, or provide `checkmerge` as an argument of your function.

**Edit:**
Assuming you want your function to return `doc`, you have to add `return(doc)` as the last statement in the function.

Comment: I updated the function in the question, thanks. However, now nothing happens when calling the function - neither do the objects in the workspace change nor do I get an error message. Also, is there a risk that my data is wrong due to assigning "merge" as name to the objects? I did not get any error messages regarding that, but is there a risk that the data got compromised?

Comment: You have to add `return(doc)` in the end of the function to return `doc`

Comment: Thanks! But there are now 2 issues: first, I need to return the merged file (z) and also the updated checkmerge file (doc). How can I return two objects? Second, the return leads to a printout in the console. How can I get R to update the objects stored in the workspace instead of only printing to the console?

Comment: 1) `return(list(doc = doc, z = z))`

Comment: 2) `results <- fun.docmerge( ... ); z <- results$z; doc <- results$doc`

Comment: Thanks - this works. The only problem is that you now need to manually extract the results and assign to the relevant object. For instance, the `doc` variable from within the function should after evaluation be again `checkmerge` in the workspace. More complicated is `z`, which should have the same name as object as specified in the function argument (`file3`). Is there a way so I do not have to specify this after the evaluation of the function? Also, if the function output is one `results` object I need to manually split it up by assigning by name. Is there a way to eliminate manual steps?

Comment: There sure is, but this is starting to get out of the scope of your question. I suggest you break your issues into smaller parts and post new questions.

Comment: Agreed. Could you please just point me into a possible direction to do it so I can make the question as specific as possible? I would then accept your answer on this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158600/discussion-between-tobiasegli-te-and-deca).